# Extracting filtered table data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I was wondering if it is possible to extract the filtered data from a table which has been filtered using the JQuery tableSorter plugin/widget.

I have a large table shown, and I then filter/sort it using the normal tablesorter functionality - but what I would like to do is be able to take this smaller table and export some data from it

it's a list of members - so I want to be able to export data (eg email addresses) from the filtered (eg all over a certain age) data so I can then send emails to these select people without having to manually type them etc.

Is this easy to do? I don't mind if I have to write something myself if someone can point me in the right direction on where to start etc?

Thanks for any help you can give,
Chris

Comment: Are you using the original tablesorter? If so, which filter plugin are you using? Or are you using my [forked version of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/)?

Comment: Hi Mottie, I'm using the original version with the zebra and filter plugins. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Sorry Mottie I didnt notice you replied so quickly.. It's just the standard/provided plugin..

The JS file has this at the top:
'tableSorter 2.4+ widgets - updated 12/26/2012'

I defined it simply using the following line in my initialisation of 
$("#memberListTable").tablesorter({
...
widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],

Comment: So it looks like you are using the forked version... I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you would need to do is find the visible table cells and save their data.

I wasn't sure how you wanted the data to be exported, so I opted for csv in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/369/):

```
$('.export').on('click', function(){
    var csv = [];
    // find only visible rows; we're ignoring filtered/hidden rows
    $('table').find('tbody tr:visible').find('td').each(function(){
        csv.push( $(this).text() );
    });
    // do what you want with the csv data here
    $('textarea').val( csv.join(',') )
});
```

Comment: Use `on()` when you have jQuery v1.7+. For older versions of jQuery use `bind()`. In reference to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936538/javascript-jquery-tablesorter-extracting-filtered-data-to-csv-file/15962879)